# Ignite is returning only a subset of the expected output of a long running query

Tags: python-3.x, h2, ignite

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 
Apache Ignite: 2.9.0 (latest)

Data Loaded: (Olist Brazilian e-commerce dataset from Kaggle)
2 tables: 
orders: 100k records 
order_payments: 100k records

Indexed Columns: 
order_payments: `CREATE INDEX idx_order_payments ON order_payments (id, order_id, payment_type)` 
orders: `CREATE INDEX idx_orders ON orders (order_id,customer_id,order_status,order_purchase_timestamp)`

Total taking up ~400 MB of space in Ignite Off-heap and Persistence.

I'm performing a simple SQL query:

```sql
    SELECT orders.order_status, 
           order_payments.payment_type, 
           SUM(order_payments.payment_value) AS total_payments
    FROM order_payments
    JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = order_payments.order_id
    GROUP BY orders.order_status, order_payments.payment_type
    ORDER BY total_payments DESC
```

I'm running Apache Ignite in a docker container.

This is the cache template configuration:

```xml
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <list>
        <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration"
              id="cache-template-bean">
            <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to
            the name of the template -->
            <property name="name" value="tbl_pll*"/>
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
            <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            <property name="queryParallelism" value="4"/>
            <!-- Other cache parameters -->
        </bean>
        <bean abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration"
              id="cache-template-bean">
            <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to
            the name of the template -->
            <property name="name" value="tbl_hf_pll*"/>
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
            <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            <property name="queryParallelism" value="2"/>
            <!-- Other cache parameters -->
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

When I use `tbl_pll` cache template for tables, the result set (for the query) is approximately (1 / queryParallelism) * Number of values in table.
So, in `tbl_pll`'s case, it returns approximately 1/4 of the expected output.

I tried the same with `queryParallelism=2` and that gives me approximately 1/2th output.

I also tried not using any cache template thus using the default value of `queryParallelism` parameter i.e. 1 and this returned the full result.

Expected full output (and output when `queryParallelism=1`):

```
[['delivered', 'credit_card', 12101094.87999937]
 ['delivered', 'boleto', 2769932.57999998]
 ['delivered', 'voucher', 343013.19]
 ['delivered', 'debit_card', 208421.12]]
```

With `queryParallelism=4`:

```
[['delivered', 'credit_card', 4064387.2800000096], 
 ['delivered', 'boleto', 918272.54], 
 ['delivered', 'voucher', 110648.45000000004], 
 ['delivered', 'debit_card', 64584.53000000001]]
```

With `queryParallelism=2`:

```
[['delivered', 'credit_card', 6129872.129999977], 
 ['delivered', 'boleto', 1360427.3799999985], 
 ['delivered', 'voucher', 168392.55999999976], 
 ['delivered', 'debit_card', 107637.38999999996]]
```

What I suspect:
queryparallelism is using the segmented index, the output is based on what was in the last/first index segment.
Either the reduce isn't working properly and the output isn't being merged from all threads, or Ignite is only running one thread and returning the output after reduce.

Since I have added order_payments's payment_type column to the index, the output seems to be almost perfectly being divided by the number of threads/index segments.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Edit:
I'm running only 1 instance of Apache Ignite.

Also, the output of the EXPLAIN keyword:

```sql
SELECT
    __Z1.ORDER_STATUS AS __C0_0,
    __Z0.PAYMENT_TYPE AS __C0_1,
    SUM(__Z0.PAYMENT_VALUE) AS __C0_2
FROM PUBLIC.ORDERS __Z1
    /* PUBLIC.ORDERS.__SCAN_ */
INNER JOIN PUBLIC.ORDER_PAYMENTS __Z0
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_ORDER_PAYMENTS: ORDER_ID = __Z1.ORDER_ID */
    ON 1=1
WHERE __Z1.ORDER_ID = __Z0.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY __Z1.ORDER_STATUS, __Z0.PAYMENT_TYPE'], ['SELECT
    __C0_0 AS ORDER_STATUS,
    __C0_1 AS PAYMENT_TYPE,
    CAST(CAST(SUM(__C0_2) AS DOUBLE) AS DOUBLE) AS TOTAL_PAYMENTS
FROM PUBLIC.__T0
    /* PUBLIC."merge_scan" */
GROUP BY __C0_0, __C0_1
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: how are you creating the cache? How are you running the query? as a guess: you need to either co-locate your data or enable distributed joins.

Comment: I'm creating using Ignite SQL ddl command CREATE TABLE to create the cache and I'm running a single instance/node of Apache Ignite.

Comment: Affinity colocation didn't work. However, setting `distributed_joins=True` when running the query did and returned the correct result. However, the time taken by query with `queryParallelism` = 4 is the same as the time taken with default parallelism of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the tables are [co-located](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/data-modeling/affinity-collocation). Use the [`affinityKey` parameter of the `CREATE TABLE` command](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/sql-reference/ddl#create-table) to group the data together.

Also, check that the Ignite SQL engine [selects the best index](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/sql-tuning#using-the-explain-statement). Generally, once you set the `affinityKey` pointing to the `order_id` column, then the `order_id` index needs to be selected during the join.

Comment: I'm using a single Ignite node and the query seems to be selecting the correct index. I'll try the affinitykey and collocation, however, I'm not sure if they are required if I'm running a single node instance.

Comment: I tried the affinity colocation and set the key (default is primary key col), however, that didn't work (docs make it seem like it should work) and the only thing that worked was setting `distributed_joins=True` as a parameter when running the query. However, the time taken when setting query parallelism to 4 is now the same as that taken by one thread.